# Difference between $ L_1 = \{(a^n b^n)^m \mid n, m \ge 1\} $ and $ L_2 = \{a^n b^n \mid n \ge 1\}^+ $

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, regular-expressions

Is there any difference between saying
$ L_1 = \{(a^n b^n)^m \mid n, m \ge 1\} $
with $ L_2 = \{a^n b^n \mid n \ge 1\}^+ $?

I know that for $v = abab$ we have $v \in L_1$ and $v \in L_2$

my understanding is that there is no difference between them and for $w = abaaabbb$ we have $ w \in L_1$ and $w \in L_2$ . but I have a feeling that maybe $w \notin L_1$, because it doesn't have the same $n$ for different $a^n b^n$.

Also, does the same apply for Kleene star $*$ too? for example if we have  $ L_3 = \{(a^n b^n)^m \mid n \ge 1, m \ge 0\} $ and $ L_4 = \{a^n b^n \mid n \ge 1\}^* $, Are $L_3$ and $L_4$ equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $abaaabbb \notin L_1$ because the string is not of the form $(a^nb^n)^m$ which is the repetition of a fixed string with the same number of $a$ and $b$.

The language $L_2$ is the Kleene closure of $\{a^nb^n \mid n\ge1\}$, consisting of all arbitrary concatenations of strings of the form $a^nb^n$. We can choose different strings of this form, and do not have to stick with the same one each time, like in $L_1$. Hence $L_2$ contains $abaaabbb$.

As for your original version of the question (now edited) it contained the notation $\{(a^nb^n)^+ \mid n\ge1\}$. I would not denote a language that way. The Kleene plus is a language operator, which takes a language (set of strings), and turns it into a language. By writing $\{(a^nb^n)^+ \mid n\ge1\}$ you get the set $(a^nb^n)^+$ within the set brackets, which can be called a "type error".

Comment: Thanks! I changed the question to the correct form so people with the same problem can search and find the answer.